# Elasticsearch Failed to find analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have created a custom analyzer for an index, and after implementing it, when i try to use `analyze` to see whether its working or not, it returns the following error `ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [lyzer]]"`

I defined the analyzer as follows

```
post trial/settings
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngrm":{
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "4",
          "max_gram": "8"
          }
      },

  "filter": {
    "myFilter": {
      "type": "word_delimiter",
      "generated_word_parts": "true",
      "generated_number_parts": "true"
    }
  },

  "analyzer": {
    "lyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "ngrm",
      "filter": ["word_delimiter","myFilter"]
      }
    }
  }

 }
}
```

When i try to verify if the analyzer is working or not, i get the following error

```
GET /trial/_analyze?analyzer=lyzer&text=some_random_text_here
{


"error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [lyzer]]",
   "status": 400
}
```

I even tried to put mappings and declare the analyzer there, but in vain!!

What other approach shall i try? ES is desperate not to find the analyzer i defined!!

Comment: have you tried `POST trial/_settings` i.e. with an underscore in `_settings`?

Comment: just did, throws another error  
`InvalidTypeNameException[mapping type name [_settings] can't start with '_'];`
 Guess i cannot use _, i am using Sense ( and Marvel)

Comment: Because [you need to use `PUT`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings), my bad I forgot to mention it in my previous comment.

Comment: how could i forget `put`!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a different approach, and it worked (excluded the settings to go in the body). Here's how it goes.

```
put trial
{
  "settings" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "lyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "nizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "nizer" : {
                        "type" : "nGram",
                        "min_gram" : "4",
                        "max_gram" : "8",
                                                }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks to @Val for suggesting `put`. (`post` did work but created the index everytime). Also, on this case i already had an index which is why `put` worked.